# Get the sum of a column in oracle reports

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, report, conditional-statements

I am trying to get the sum of a column using oracle reports, but with a condition. For example I have three columns, a store column, a fruit column and a cost column. I want to get the sum cost of all the "bananas", or whichever fruit you pick, bought in a particular store.

Ex:

store1------------banana----------------$5.00

store1------------apple-----------------$2.00

store1------------banana----------------$3.50

store 1 bananas = **$8.50 <- this is what I want**

store 1 sum = $10.50

store2------------apples----------------$1.50
etc

I've tried making a formula in the data model, but then I'd have to supply it with the store name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115) function, wich is a ANSI SQL function. You also need to use group by:

```
select store_name, fruit_name, sum(cost)as Total_Cost
from your_table
group by store_name, fruit_name
```